# When running bash script that calls another script getting EOF error

Tags: bash, scripting

The other script is just read statement that will be echo'ed into a file from this script

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
#  createdb_wrapper.scr
#  Log information about user of createdb.scr



Default_Dir=/export/home/cwatts/test

Default_Log=DB.Audit

while [ -z "${fname}" ]

do

echo "Please, enter your Fullname [ENTER]:"

read fname

done
```

Tried various ways to pull the information from the other script
    dbname="./createDB.scr | awk '{print $1}'"

```
sh $dbname

while [ -z "${desc}" ]

do

    echo "Please,enter a brief Description [ENTER]:

    read desc

done



 #Checks the directory exists, and creates if not

 if [ ! -d $Default_Dir ] ;then

    echo "directory doesn't exit, it will be created"

    mkdir $Default_Dir

fi

 echo `date -u` '|' $dbname '|'  $fname '|'  $desc >> $Default_Dir/$Default_Log

exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the other quote:

```
echo "Please,enter a brief Description [ENTER]:
```

Should be

```
echo "Please,enter a brief Description [ENTER]:"
```

I also recommend this form:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# createdb_wrapper.scr
# Log information about user of createdb.scr
#

DEFAULT_DIR='/export/home/cwatts/test'
DEFAULT_LOG='DB.Audit'

until read -p "Please, enter your Fullname [ENTER]: " FNAME && [[ -n $FNAME ]]; do
    :
done

until read -p "Please,enter a brief Description [ENTER]: " DESC && [[ -n $DESC ]]; do
    :
done

if [[ -d $DEFAULT_DIR ]]; then
    echo "Directory does not exist. It will be created."
    mkdir "$DEFAULT_DIR"
fi

echo "$(exec date -u) | $DBNAME | $FNAME | $DESC" >> "$DEFAULT_DIR/$DEFAULT_LOG"
```

Note: `$DBNAME` is not set.

Comment: DOH, Thanks very much konsolebox